# Returning values Batch files that CALL functions with SETLOCAL set

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, environment-variables

`SETLOCAL` ... `ENDLOCAL` innoculate local variables so completely that Functions which try to compute values and return them fail.
Typically, these are functions that parse files and strings with `for`-`do` and which rely on `SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion` to compute values.

Over the years I've gotten around the problem by passing the value to a temp file and recovering it, as in the example below.

However . . . . This is  *v e e e r y*  slow, especially when recursion is involved, because of the continual read/write/create cycles taking place.

Even System-wide variables created by `SETX` fail, because `SETLOCAL` creates and releases local versions. It's bulletproof ~ or seems to be.

Over the years I've returned to the problem, an itch I keep scratching. Maybe someone out there has solved it? Here's the sample code:

### Sample Code

```
@echo off
set _str=
call :RandomFunction %*
:: back from the function
echo:
echo: now try to recover the variables
set _ & echo: _ReturnStr not there
echo:
echo: so collect it from the temp file
for /f "delims=" %%V in ('more^<_passvalue.txt') do set _str=%%V

echo: [%_str%] is returned
echo: *sigh* there must be a better way!
exit /b
```

### This Function is called:

```
:RandomFunction
@echo off
set _anotherstr=asdfg

setlocal & rem most times enabledelayedexpansion

set _localReturnValue=
echo: this function is invoked and [%*] set of parameters comes in 
:: and stuff happens
:: at the end of it all a value is ready to be returned!

set "_localReturnValue=ImBreakingOut" & rem this is it
:: at the same time send it to a file
echo:%_localReturnValue%>_passValue.txt
endlocal

SET "_ReturnStr=%_localReturnValue%" & rem trying to recover it to be returned
echo: trying to echo the _ReturnStr= [%_ReturnStr%] after ENDLOCAL
echo: Post ENDLOCAL it was released
echo: but _anotherstr= [%_anotherstr%] does persist
exit /b
:: /RandomFunction
```

#### The output to the console is

```
>f 123 abc
 this function is invoked and [123 abc] set of parameters comes in
 trying to echo the _ReturnStr= [] after ENDLOCAL
 Post ENDLOCAL it was released
 but _anotherstr= [asdfg] does persist

 now try to recover the variables
_anotherstr=asdfg
 _ReturnStr not there

 so collect it from the temp file
 [ImBreakingOut] is returned
 *sigh* there must be a better way!
>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### the answer is Tunneling

Oh dear. I am an idiot.
Frank Sinatra had the answer. George Clooney too.
it's called "tunneling" aaarghh.
sheesh, how easily we forget.

**Simon shepherd** lays it out very nicely in his SS64 site on his [How to Create and use a Batch file Function](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-functions.html) page:

> The solution to this is to take advantage of the fact that the CMD
>   shell evaluates variables on a line-by-line basis - so placing
>   ENDLOCAL **on the same line** as the SET statement(s) gives the result we
>   want. This technique is known as 'tunneling' and works for both
>   functions and entire batch scripts

#### Re-writing the code

```
@echo off
call :RandomFunction %*
:: back from the function
echo:
echo: now recover the variable created in the function
echo: the value of variable _ReturnStr = [%_ReturnStr%]
echo:
echo: so no need to collect from a temp file
echo: *sigh* there has always beeen a better way!
exit /b

:RandomFunction
@echo off
setlocal & rem most times enabledelayedexpansion

set _localReturnValue=
echo: this function is invoked and [%*] set of parameters comes in 
:: and stuff happens
:: at the end of it all a value is ready to be returned!

set "_localReturnValue=ImBreakingOut" & rem this is it
:: concurrently execute the variable assignment wit the ENDLOCAL command
endlocal & SET "_ReturnStr=%_localReturnValue%"

exit /b
:: /RandomFunction
```

#### now gives the correct answer

```
>_temp abc 123
 this function is invoked and [abc 123] set of parameters comes in

 now recover the variable created in the function
 the value of variable _ReturnStr = [ImBreakingOut]

 so no need to collect from a temp file
 *sigh* there has always beeen a better way!

>
```